# Calling TransformToVisual right after changing Parent won't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using `TransformToVisual` to get the position of a control relatively to its parent. I need this position just after after adding this control to a `StackPanel`, however, the result I obtain is a `(0, 0)` translation.

If delay this method with a `Task` by a millisecond, the result is good.

I don't understand this behaviour as I am not doing any threading. Does someone have a solution to deal with this (without tasks) ?

Here is the shortened code :

```
public readonly Point position;

public Container(Box box) {
    InitializeComponent();

    //StackPanel with custom margins and centered alignment
    stackPanel.Children.Add(box);

    position = this.TransformToVisual(box).Transform(new Point(0, 0))
}
```

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with this... https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1034445/Understanding-MeasureOverride-and-ArrangeOverride

Answer (score 1):

When you add a child there the control is in the child and the measure and arrange mechanism is used to work out where it should be to centralise it.
Because you make the call straight after adding the control, moving the thing around will not have happened yet.
There are a number of ways you could get the position once it's finished moving about.
You don't seem to be doing anything much immediately with position so you could make an expression. If you use it later and need it just the once:

```
public Point position() => this.TransformToVisual(box).Transform(new Point(0, 0))
;
```

Or
Force the layout process by calling UpdateLayout

```
stackPanel.Children.Add(box);
stackpanel.UpdateLayout();
position = this.TransformToVisual(box).Transform(new Point(0, 0))
```

Or
Defer the calculation by using dispatcher.

```
stackPanel.Children.Add(box);
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action(() => 
{  
   position = this.TransformToVisual(box).Transform(new Point(0, 0))

}), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

Comment: In fact, I have to initialize a custom control, and some parts of it depends on the position of some other elements, so the position is required in the same call stack.
The second solution looks appealing, but doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: If you're still stuck then I think a sample which is self contained and demonstrates just this issue would be an idea. That way people can replicate what you're seeing and explore the issue.